# What is the purpose of setImageResource() in Android?

Tags: android

If an image is already defined in Xml and when I run the app, it pops of on the screen of the emulator without any problem, what's the purpose of `setImageResource()` method in Java code ?

Comment: you might also want to change it programmatically ?

Comment: If you don't want to set image to xml file and show image programmatically then you need to use this method. For E.g. You set image in xml which showing ON Switch now when you click ON Button its should be set to OFF Switch so in that case you can set using this setImageResource() programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set an image resource programmatically into **ImageView** by using the **setImageResource()** method:
Example:

```
 ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
 // supossing to have an image called ic_play inside my drawables.
 myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
```

Answer (score 1):

for any dynamically programming you might need to change the content of an ImageView at runTime and for this according to your resource that might comes from web service you can do it with

```
setImageResource(int resId)

setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)

setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)
```